# How should these translated takeoff and climb settings be interpreted?

Tags: takeoff, v-speeds, climb

I am having difficulties understanding this transcript. It is originally not in English, so I was wondering if anyone could help me to make sense of this and also help me  with the correct wording in English. The training cap originally says

> after the ground roll (four engine turboprop) : 12 degrees nose-up; 1500 feet; decrease power/ reduce engine thrust power (?); climb speed (?); flaps up.

I know that usually at around 1000 feet agl the pitch is lowered so I imagine that was an order to lower the pitch to 12 degrees nose up or a confirmation of that. Does that make sense? Would one lower it after the final phase of the initial climb?

Then there is the mention to decrease power. Would power be reduced at height?

I've found a document from a flight school that says power is reduced to remain in the traffic pattern, but that was after 2500 feet. And I found a skybraero page that says that after 1500 ft aal one would "reduce thrust to climb power". Would reducing thrust make more sense than reducing power? I thought they both meant the same thing. How are they different?

At the end, when (I think) he says climb speed. I found nothing about climb speed specifically... since this is said after the final phase of the initial climb out (that goes up to 1500 ft), when climb to cruise phase starts, would it make more sense if that read climb to cruise speed/ cruise climb speed (Vcc)?

Comment: It may help if you noted the model of aircraft involved, there are a number of 4 engine turboprops that may have different procedures. Some engines can't use full take-off power for more than some period of time, so the procedure is to lower the power setting.

Answer (score 4):

> 12 degrees nose up

Since it says this comes after the ground roll, it sounds like this is the pitch you rotate to when you reach rotation speed. You then hold this pitch for the initial climb out.

> 1500 feet; decrease power/reduce engine thrust power

In English, generally "power" is used on propeller aircraft, and "thrust" used on jet aircraft. Other languages might not translate exactly. On a turboprop airplane, you would have power levers, which you use to select a power setting. At this point, you would decrease the power setting to a climb/continuous setting.

> climb speed

This just means you will fly whatever speed you plan in climbing at. This would depend on the aircraft, and the flight. Especially larger, higher performance aircraft will have some standard "climb speed" that is used during climb, to balance ground speed and rate of climb. "Cruise climb" may be used to describe a slower climb where emphasis is placed on a higher ground speed. In smaller aircraft there may be less performance margin. This wording may also be leaving it open, as on some flights you may want best rate/angle of climb, others would use a regular climb speed.

Answer (score 2):

It would be common for the takeoff power setting to be higher than the climb power setting, and also common to climb steeply to 1000 (or 1500, depending on the specific procedures of the operator) feet, then reduce pitch in order to acelerate.  As speed builds, the flaps would be retracted.  Also at about this point (either when pitch is reduced or after the flaps are fully retracted), it's common to reduce the power from the takeoff power to climb power.  In general, twelve degrees of pitch seems about right for the target attitude for the initial climb.  (In comparison, the 737 uses 15 to 20 degrees as the pitch target for the initial climb to flap retraction altitude, reduced to 10 degrees to accelerate; that a turboprop's initial climb would be slightly less steep seems reasonable.)

To "reduce thrust" and to "reduce power" are essentially synonymous, and if different writers use different terms there, it doesn't reflect anything significant.

The initial climib at 1000 or 1500 feet is typically performed at a speed slightly above takeoff speed; the climb from that point to cruise altitude is typically performed at a speed referred to as "climb speed", and then at cruise the aircraft will fly its "cruise speed" which is usually (not always -- there are exceptions, especially when using Mach Number as the reference for the higher stages of the climb) somewhat faster than the climb speed.